# No content after smarty gzip filter

Tags: php, smarty, gzip

I tried smarty gzip plugin [smarty gzip plugin](http://smarty.incutio.com/?page=GZipPlugin).

```
    $stpl->loadFilter('output','gzip'); 
$stpl->display('file:'.$cnf->site_root.$cnf->client_tpl_path.$slang.'/main.tpl');
```

After this, my site look like that:

[image: screenshot]

I don't know why my browser not decoded gzip.

Comment: [solved] our server using live compression and content was compressed twice.